# computeExpression - Having a hard time getting it to work...

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics-cloud

Trying to get computeExpression to group my opportunity amount, but am having a really hard time getting it to work. I upload the following JSON, registers the dataset fine, but when I try to find the new Opportunity_Size field on a lense it doesn't appear... any suggestions?`

> `{
>     "101": {
>       "action": "sfdcDigest",
>       "parameters": {
>         "object": "Opportunity",
>         "fields": [
>           {
>             "name": "ACV_Equiv_No_Milestone__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "RecordTypeId"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Sales_Rep2__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "AccountId"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Record_Type_ID__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Type"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "CloseDate"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Account_ID__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "ForecastCategoryName"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "ForecastCategory"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "StageName"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Wave_ACV_Bucket__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Opportunity_Service_Ratio__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Total_Contract_Value_LSE_NM__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Probability"
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     },
>     "102": {
>       "action": "sfdcDigest",
>       "parameters": {
>         "fields": [
>           {
>             "name": "Name"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Id"
>           }
>         ],
>         "object": "RecordType"
>       }
>     },
>     "103": {
>       "action": "sfdcDigest",
>       "parameters": {
>         "fields": [
>           {
>             "name": "Current_Manager__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Name"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Sales_Team_Name__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Id"
>           }
>         ],
>         "object": "Sales_Reps__c"
>       }
>     },
>     "104": {
>       "action": "sfdcDigest",
>       "parameters": {
>         "fields": [
>           {
>             "name": "Name"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Full_Name__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Id"
>           }
>         ],
>         "object": "User"
>       }
>     },
>     "105": {
>       "action": "sfdcDigest",
>       "parameters": {
>         "fields": [
>           {
>             "name": "Date_of_Order__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Industry"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Industry_Clean__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Industry_Zoom__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "NumberOfEmployees"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Number_of_employees_Clean__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Headcount_zoom__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Wave_Employee_Bucket__c"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "BillingCountry"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Name"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "Id"
>           }
>         ],
>         "object": "Account"
>       }
>     },
>     "106": {
>       "action": "augment",
>       "parameters": {
>         "right_key": [
>           "Id"
>         ],
>         "left": "101",
>         "left_key": [
>           "RecordTypeId"
>         ],
>         "right_select": [
>           "Name"
>         ],
>         "right": "102",
>         "relationship": "RecordTypeId"
>       }
>     },
>     "107": {
>       "action": "augment",
>       "parameters": {
>         "right_key": [
>           "Id"
>         ],
>         "left": "106",
>         "left_key": [
>           "Sales_Rep2__c"
>         ],
>         "right_select": [
>           "Current_Manager__c",
>           "Name",
>           "Sales_Team_Name__c"
>         ],
>         "right": "103",
>         "relationship": "Sales_Rep2__c"
>       }
>     },
>     "108": {
>       "action": "augment",
>       "parameters": {
>         "right_key": [
>           "Id"
>         ],
>         "left": "107",
>         "left_key": [
>           "Sales_Rep2__c.Current_Manager__c"
>         ],
>         "right_select": [
>           "Name",
>           "Full_Name__c"
>         ],
>         "right": "104",
>         "relationship": "Sales_Rep2__c.Current_Manager__c"
>       }
>     },
>     "109": {
>       "action": "augment",
>       "parameters": {
>         "right_key": [
>           "Id"
>         ],
>         "left": "108",
>         "left_key": [
>           "AccountId"
>         ],
>         "right_select": [
>           "Date_of_Order__c",
>           "Industry",
>           "Name",
>           "Industry_Clean__c",
>           "Industry_Zoom__c",
>           "Wave_Employee_Bucket__c",
>           "NumberOfEmployees",
>           "Number_of_employees_Clean__c",
>           "Headcount_zoom__c",
>           "BillingCountry"
>         ],
>         "right": "105",
>         "relationship": "AccountId"
>       }
>     },
>     "110": {
>       "action": "computeExpression",
>       "parameters": {
>         "source": "101",
>         "mergeWithSource": true,
>         "computedFields": [
>           {
>             "name": "Opportunity_Size",
>             "type": "Text",
>             "label": "Opportunity_Size",
>             "saqlExpression": "case  when ACV_Equiv_No_Milestone__c < 50000 then \"<50K\" when ACV_Equiv_No_Milestone__c >= 50000 then \">50K\" else \"ERROR\" end"
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     },
>     "111": {
>       "action": "sfdcRegister",
>       "parameters": {
>         "alias": "OppCompute",
>         "name": "OppCompute",
>         "source": "110"
>       }
>     }
>   }`

Comment: Refresh the cache of browser sometimes as the data is heavily cached .